# Launch apps using its package name and bring it to front if it is already running

Tags: android

How to launch any app like messenger,chrome,etc by using its package name but if the launched is already running on the background I want it to just bring to front.I don't want to create new instance of it Is there any solution.I am testing my app on api 23 (lollipop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked, this code works like charm.

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.abc");
LaunchIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

Comment: will the above code bring the already background running app to foreground:)

Comment: Hi,your code is working perfect But there is a bug,If i launch an app for e.g. messaging app from inside my app using your code it perfectly launches the app and bring it to front if it is already running in background but when I launch the the same messaging app from my android default launcher it just creates a new instance of messaging app on above of my already running messaging app which was launched before by my app:(  Is there any solution for this..